# Where is the file angular-cli.json in the new @angular/cli version?

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli

I'm new in angular2 and i have tried to create a project with cli, but when I try to change the css adding it in angular-cli.json, I have detected that this file is not created...

Can I create manually or this file has been changed for another one?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `angular-cli.json` should be located in the root folder of the project.  This is using the latest version `"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3"`.

As for creating it if it is missing or maybe accidentally deleted, you could try that since the original version is pretty generic.  Here is what it should look like right after project creation:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
    "name": "testproj"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

You could also try generating a new project with the cli with `ng new PROJECT_NAME` and see if it contains the `angular-cli.json` file.

Answer (score 121):

### Angular 6 and later

`angular-cli.json` file has been renamed/replaced with `angular.json` in version 6 of Angular.

It's a different file format and not just a rename :

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace

Comment: The documentation for this file and its formatting is here: [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace).  This is for Angular CLI 6

Comment: @Weikardzaena thanks for adding this. It's a file format change too and not just a rename as my answer probably implied.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but if we have upgraded to 6 then is it safe to delete the angular-cli.json file being that the newer angular.json file is present ?

Comment: Yes you can delete the old one safely.

Answer (score 36):

The file was changed to be a hidden file now on unix/linux systems. It is now `.angular-cli.json`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the global CLI config, I found it here on Windows:

%USERPROFILE%\angular-config.json

**Example config change**

```
ng config -g cli.defaultCollection @angular-eslint/schematics
```

**Change is saved here**

C:\users\USERNAME-GOES-HERE\angular-config.json

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics",
    "packageManager": "yarn",
    "warnings": {
      "versionMismatch": false
    }
  }
}
```