# Running lint fails after installing angular2-notifications

Tags: angular, npm, lint, tslint

I have created a new Angular4 project using Angular-CLI recently.

The problem I am having is after installing [angular2-notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications) , I get an error when running the `ng lint` command.

**Error** :

> Failed to load C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\angular2-notifications\tslint.json: Could not find custom rule directory: C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\angular2-notifications\node_modules\codelyzer

Stacktrace :

```
at new FatalError (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\tslint\lib\error.js:40:23)
at Object.findConfiguration (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\tslint\lib\configuration.js:47:15)
at files.forEach (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\lint.js:36:50)
at Array.forEach (native)
at lintConfigs.map (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\lint.js:30:19)
at Array.map (native)
at Class.run (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\lint.js:21:14)
at Class.run (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\lint.js:45:25)
at Class.Command.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:128:15)
at C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\GitHub\Go-NoGo\GoNoGo\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:92:22
```

I have turned to Google for this issue, without any luck. I have been to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications) and had no luck there either.

Then I went in the actual `tslint.json` file of angular2-notifications package.

I see this at the top :

```
"rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
],
```

When I remove those 3 lines, the `ng lint` command works.

My question is, am I missing something here? I need this command to work and I don't think that modifying the package is an acceptable solution. Is this a bug in the package itself which I should report to them?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exclude node_modules from your lint config in angular-cli.json:

```
"lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**/*"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**/*"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**/*"
    }]
```

The angular2-notifications project obviously shouldn't break ng lint for users. Still, I suppose it is also somewhat fair to say that a project shouldn't be trying to lint code that shouldn't be edited.

Comment: `angular-cli.json` file has been renamed/replaced with `angular.json` in version 6 of Angular. The format of the file changed as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184006/7769052

Comment: in my case we are using customized angular frame work and angular.json file is not there(neither angular-li.json) where to add those configurations then

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I got the message was the absence of `node_modules` directory. After I ran `npm install`, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found the solution by providing correct path for the node_modules.

I mean mine project is an ASP.net with Angular - Where directory structure is customized and "package.json" kept outside the angular app, Hence node_modules was also residing to the same directory where "package.json" is present.

So I was able to fix this issue by changing the "node_modules" path in tslint.ts as

```
"rulesDirectory": [
    "./../node_modules/codelyzer"
],
```