# Where do I declare load paths for SASS files in Angular 8.x?

Tags: angular, sass, configuration

According to [docs on SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#load-paths), I'm supposed to specify load path by adding *stylePreprocessorOptions* in [config file *.angular.cli.json*](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components) as shown below.

```
"root": "src",
...
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [ "./stylings" ]
}
```

The config file has [changed its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395200/where-is-the-file-angular-cli-json-in-the-new-angular-cli-version) repeatedly, now being *angular.json*. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184006/1525840), the new files has not only new syntax but also [new schematics](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace).

I can't really figure out where to put the old config specification in the new format nor whether it's changed its name or format.

How do I do this now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample `angular.json` file:

```
"projects": {
  "app-name": {
    "projectType": "application",
    "root": "apps/app-name",
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "."
            ]
          }
    ...
}
```

Read more on the [workspace config](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config). Remember to restart the application after altering the *angular.json* file. (Even if the browser reloads the app on save, HMR doesn't respect changes outside the source directory. And the aforementioned file resides in the root.)

Comment: What is the dot referring to? My globals reside in the *~/src/app/global.scss* and it seems that using that path in the config gave the expected result. It's +1 for speed and to-the-pointness, though. I see that I have *src/favicon.ico* elsewhere in the file, so I tried *src/app* but it still scream at me in the console...

Comment: Scratch that. I didn't realize that I had to restart *ng serve* after altering the stupid config file.

Comment: ha, the _to-the-pointness_ wasn't entirely intentional, had to run off to a meeting :p